# Select the node from xml file and update it-C# console

Tags: c#, xml

I want to update the node in xml file.I want to check the loginid and increment it by 1. I have been trying something like this but the xml file is not getting updated.

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load("tempLogonoff.xml");
XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//tblTemp/Login/LoginId");
node.Attributes[0].Value = (LoginId + 1).ToString();
xAnd I have a following Xml File:mlDoc.Save("tempLogonoff.xml");
```

And I have following Xml code

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<tblTemp>
  <Login>
    <LoginId>3</LoginId>
    <AgentId>2</AgentId>
    <OracleId>763887</OracleId>
  </Login>
  <Login>
    <LoginId>2</LoginId>
    <AgentId>1</AgentId>
    <OracleId>763602</OracleId>
  </Login>
</tblTemp>
```

So if my agentId changes,that login id should change.

I am getting an exception-"The index being passed in is out of range."Can you please help me on this same.

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting the [`InnerText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.innertext(v=vs.110).aspx) of the node and not its attributes (as it doesn't have any):

```
XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//tblTemp/Login/LoginId");
node.InnerText = (LoginId + 1).ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks.It is incrementing the loginId,But I want to increment it with respect to agentId and oracleId.